# PHP with Bootstrap Carousel

Tags: php, html, twitter-bootstrap

Im trying to learn PHP and using it with the Bootstrap library for my site.  I am looking to use the bootstrap carousel as seen [here](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel)

What I am trying to achieve is the carousel with captions and the Machine Name I am showing in the picture would be a hyperlink that will take you to that page for more info.  I have a MySQL database that contains the machine name and the ImagePath as to where it is located.

So my code currently is as below -

```
<?php
                while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
                {
        ?>
      <div class="bs-example">
      <div id="carousel-example-captions" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
          <li data-target="#carousel-example-captions" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
          <li data-target="#carousel-example-captions" data-slide-to="1"></li>
          <li data-target="#carousel-example-captions" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        </ol>
          <img data-src="holder.js/900x800/auto/#777:#777" style="height: 400px; width: 400px;" alt="First slide image" src="<?php echo $row['MachineImagePath'] ?>"/>
     <div class="finlay-carousel-caption">
        <h3><?php echo $row['MachineName']?></h3>
          <div>
            <p>
             Click the link above for more details about <?php echo $row['MachineName']>
            </p>
          </div>
                <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-captions" data-slide="prev">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
        </a>
        <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-captions" data-slide="next">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
        </a>
      </div>
     </div>
      </div>
        <?php
                }
                mysql_close($connection);
        ?>
```

Currently instead of placing each image inside the carosuel this is creating a new carousel for each image down the page.  Should the `<carousel-example-captions>` html be outside the while loop so it is created once and then the img tag will pick up the new image for each slide as you click the next > and prev < buttons.

Note also - `<h3><?php echo $row['MachineName']?></h3>` - I have not yet turned the header into a hyperlink as I wanted to get the carousel working correctly first.

Comment: if only bootstrap knew that 95% of dev's want to do this,  so put it in their docs....

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I recently added a carousel with a link from the mysql database.  The issue is that you have the create new carousel code inside of the while statement. If you take it out and just have the new slide commands inside the while it will work perfect.

```
    <div class="bs-example">
    <div id="carousel-example-captions" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <div class="carousel-inner">
<?php
    $counter = 1;
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
?>
            <div class="item<?php if($counter <= 1){echo " active"; } ?>">
                <a href="">
                    <img data-src="holder.js/900x800/auto/#777:#777" style="height: 400px; width: 400px;" alt="First slide image" src="<?php echo $row['MachineImagePath'] ?>"/>
                </a>
                <div class="finlay-carousel-caption">
                    <h3><?php echo $row['MachineName']?></h3>
                    <p>Click the link above for more details about <?php echo $row['MachineName']>; ?></p>
                </div>
            </div>
<?php
    $counter++;
    }
    mysql_close($connection);
?>

        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
           <li data-target="#carousel-example-captions" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
           <li data-target="#carousel-example-captions" data-slide-to="1"></li>
           <li data-target="#carousel-example-captions" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        </ol>
    </div>
</div>
```

If you get the number of rows from you mysql statement you can change the indicators section to have a loop that would allow for unlimited number of slides.

Comment: awesome. Any docs or references to how you get the indicators to match the number of images. such a common task but such a poorly covered subject it seems.

Answer (score 4):

I've solved this issue creating a control variable like this:

1. define a control variable: `$active = true`
2. create a loop
3. check inside a loop if `$active` is true
4. set control variable to `false` after loop ends

```php
    <?php $active = true; ?>
    <?php foreach($images as $image):?>
      <div class="carousel-item <?php echo ($active == true)?"active":"" ?>"> 
        <img src="assets/img/anuncios/<?php echo $image['image'] ?>" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
      </div>
    <?php $active = false; ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
```

This way, the active class is printed only at the first loop.

Answer (score 0):

I find most carousel software, even that based on JQuery, too complicated to configure and maintain, that's why I created my own carousel that you can download here for free: https://33hops.com/php-html5-lightweight-slideshow-carousel.html

The premises on top of which I programmed this are short and straight: I just wanted something that could automatically pick the images put in a given folder, preload them and cycle through them with a nice HTML5 transition effect and optionally texts overlayed on top. The result is an ultralight PHP carousel with an ultra low footprint ideal for mobile developments and easy maintenance, just change the images and reload.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="newoptionmenu">
        <a href="<?php echo $fullurl; ?>imports/corporate-import.xls" class="btn btn-secondary btn-lg waves-effect waves-light btn-primary-gray">Download Format</a>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-lg waves-effect waves-light btn-primary-gray" onclick="loadpop('Import Corporate Excel',this,'600px')" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bs-example-modal-center" popaction="action=importcorporateExcel">Import File</button>
        <a href="<?php echo $fullurl; ?>exportCorporate.php" target="_blank" class="btn btn-secondary btn-lg waves-effect waves-light btn-primary-gray">Export Data</a>
        <div> <?php if (strpos($LoginUserDetails["permissionAddEdit"], 'Corporate') !== false) { ?>
           <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-lg waves-effect waves-light" onclick="loadpop2('Add Corporate',this,'600px')" data-toggle="modal"  data-target="#myModal2" data-backdrop="static"  popaction="action=addcorporate" >Add Corporate</button>
           <?php } ?>
        </div>
     <div>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

```
<div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide clearfix" data-ride="carousel">
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <?php
            $tmp_post = $post;
            $query_args = array( 'suppress_filters' => false, 'post_type' => 'post' );
            $slides = get_posts( $query_args );
            if ( ! empty( $slides ) ) {
            $counter = 0;
            foreach( $slides as $post ) { setup_postdata( $post ); $counter++;
        ?>  
        <div class="item<?php if ($counter == 1) echo ' active'; ?>">
            <?php $feat_image = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($loop->ID) );?>
            <img src="<?php echo $feat_image ?>" class="img-responsive img-circle"/>
            <div class="finlay-carousel-caption">
            <?php $degisc= get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_my_meta_value_key', true );?>
            <h1><?php echo $degisc;?></h1>
            <?php $position = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_my_meta_value_key1', true );?>
            <p><?php echo $position;?></p>
            <div class="line marginBottom15"></div>
                <?php $words = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_my_meta_value_key2', true );?>
                <p><?php echo $words;?></p>
                <div class="line"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php } } 
        $post = $tmp_post;
        ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: iam guessing this is a wordpress option.