# php bootstrap carousel indicators

Tags: php, bootstrap-4, carousel, indicator

I read the solution for putting php code to create a bootstrap carousel here:

[PHP with Bootstrap Carousel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21386194/php-with-bootstrap-carousel)

But I have a bit of trouble with the indicators, if I put the php code in there, only 1 indicator appears. I would like to have as much indicators appear as there are images in my db.

Hope someone can help.

The code I have now is just the non-php code for the indicators, I always end up with only 1 indicator.

```
<!-- Wrapper for slides -->
<div class="carousel-inner">
  <?php
    $counter = 1;
    foreach($images->results() as $image){
  ?>
                    
  <div class="item<?php if($counter <= 1){echo " active"; } ?>">
    <img class="carouselimg" src="<?php echo $image->url; ?>" alt="<?php echo $image->description; ?>">
  </div>
                    
  <!-- Indicators --> //This is what I can't find
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    //also tried <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to=<?php echo $counter-1;?> class=<?php if($counter <= 1){echo 'class="active"'}?>></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
  </ol>
                    
                    <?php
                        $counter++;
                        }
                    ?>
                </div>
```

Comment: We can't help you fix a problem in your code if you don't show the code to is :) Please see how to create a [minimal,reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with your relevant code so that we are able to help.

Comment: added the code right now, it was in the link though

Comment: Questions on Stack Overflow must be self-contained and include all of the relevant information in the question itself. Also, "*I tried a few things*" what were those things? You need to give us all the relevant information so we can help and don't suggest the same things that you already tried.

Comment: Let's just say I only have this code and don't know how to do it, and I can't find it on the internet (searching on Google and stack overflow). I think it doesn't really matter what I tried already, it was obviously wrong since it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem is that you're repeatedly generating the entire indicators `<ol>` for each slide. You should only be generating the `<ol>` once, and within it you should generate a `<li>` for each slide:

```php
<!-- Wrapper for slides -->
<div class="carousel-inner">
<?php
    // Carousel items:

    $counter = 1;
    foreach($images->results() as $image){
?>
                                        
    <div class="item<?php if($counter <= 1){echo " active"; } ?>">
        <img class="carouselimg" src="<?php echo $image->url; ?>" alt="<?php echo $image->description; ?>">
    </div>
<?php
        $counter++;
    }
?>
    <!-- Indicators --> //This is what I can't find
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
<?php

    $counter = 1;
    foreach($images->results() as $image){
?>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="<?= $counter ?>" <?php if ($counter==1){ ?>class="active"<?php } ?>></li>
    </ol>
                                        
<?php
        $counter++;
    }
?>
</div>
```

Comment: Alright, now it makes sense, yes, that's it. So I was on the right track, only forgot to set a second counter, for the indicators.